# Поиск по БД MySQL через поиск на сайте

Tags: mysql, wordpress, search

Появилась необходимость реализовать достаточно простую форму поиска на сайте, но я никогда с такой задачей не сталкивался, хоть и понимаю логику всего этого.

Короткое описание по пунктам:

1. На странице будет строка поиска, в которую посетитель сайта должен ввести некое значение, и получить ответ
2. Если в базе данных имеется введенное пользователем значение, то сайт переводит на страницу А, в противном случае на страницу Б

В качестве CMS использую WordPress

Как это все реализовать?

Comment: Уточните что конкретно Вы собираетесь искать в БД. В WordPress есть стандартный поиск который умеет искать по заголовку записи и ее контенту. Поиск по БД, понятие очень растяжимое.

Comment: На данный момент в БД есть готовая таблица, которая состоит из одного столбца "catalog"
В каждой ячейке (пока их 500, но будет больше) уникальное значение (набор символов).
Поиск должен искать совпадения по этой таблице, а дальше, как я и описал в посте выше.

Comment: Для того чтобы найти что-то в таблице и вообще для работы с БД, есть [$wpdb](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb), используйте его для взаимодействия с БД. В зависимости от результата уже и делайте перенаправление. Или в чем конкретная трудность возникла?